# How to mention a user mentioned in the command discord js

Tags: discord.js

So im working on a discord bot, and working on a command where it mentions a user. For example: `-fakekick @user` and the bot would say `User has been kicked` I've read through the docs and found a few sites but I couldn't really understand it as I just started discord js a few days ago. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the user object of a mentioned user, you can very simply use the `mentions` extension of the `message` object. We can very simply use it in order to define our user, and later on, mention him in a future message. That can be done very simply as so:

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first(); // Would get the first mentioned user's object
message.channel.send(`${user} has been kicked!`); // To mention a user, you simply need to mention his user object.
```